# Is there a formula in determining the largest possible of nullity?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know rank+nullity=dimension=n. And I know largest rank is max{m,n}. I know it is possible that a matrix can have zero rank, and the nullity is n.Am I right?

Like for instance, we have a matrix 4 x 6. Am I right to say the smallest nullity we can have is 2 because n=6, so 6-4(maximum rank) gives 2. But the maximum nullity can reach to 6? Am I right to say? I am a bit confused. Can I safely say the matrix can be a full rank as long as it has 4 linearly independent rows, or 6 linearly independent columns?

Comment: Use latex syntax for your formula, please!

Answer (score 1):

Out of all $m \times n$ matrices, the maximum nullity is indeed $n$. The nullspace is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or whatever field), and the nullity is its dimension. The largest dimension possible for a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is $n$, and the $m \times n$ zero matrix achieves this upper bound.

Using the fact that the maximum rank is $\min\{m, n\}$, we can deduce that the minimum nullity is
$$n - \min\{m, n\} = n + \max\{-m, -n\} = \max\{n - m, 0\}.$$
In other words, if $n \le m$, then the minimum nullity is $0$, otherwise if $n > m$, then the minimum nullity is $n - m$.